# arch linux strange message after installing xorg and virtualbox guest additions

Tags: linux, virtualbox, xorg

I'm brand new to arch linux.
I'm following the tutorial first part and got a linux environment working on virtualbox 5.1.6

After that I installed xorg-server, xorg-xinit, twm, xterm, xf86-video
-vesa virtualbox-guest-utils (virtualbox-guest-modules-arch)

rebooted and getting following message:
[image]

and after logged in, getting this:
[image]

The same occurred also with virtualbox 5.0.26 so I upgraded to 5.1.6 and still the problem with a new installation.

Does somebody know what could be the problem?

Comment: Wrong site. Stackoverflow is for programming questions only. Perhaps try [unix.se] or [Superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. AND please copy/paste into your msg rather than using screen shots. they are hard to read and prevent expert readers from using the browser search. Thanks and Good Luck.